# How to transfer all blocks to another Topic?

Tags: bots, powerapps, power-virtual-agents

I am new to power agent bots and unfortunately I created a long conversation in one of the default locked topics. Now I cannot copy it over to a user topic in any way. Is it possible to save my work or I have to manually create everything from scratch?

I could not find an answer to this. Please excuse me if there is such a question already.